# Is EU residence permit still valid for transit through London for a Non-EU citizen(post brexit)

Tags: eu, british-airways, brexit

I'll be traveling to India via London from Helsinki in April 2019( post brexit) , I currently hold a residence premit issued by Finland, Do I need to apply to for a transit Visa (Direct Air Transit ) or I'm still exempt from it

Comment: The simple answer to this is: no one knows (yet).

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably be fine.  There are other countries whose residence permits allow an exemption; the fact that EU permits do so does not depend on UK membership in the EU.